# 'bundle install' keeps installing gem sqlite3 version 1.4.2 even if not in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I need sqlite3 v1.3.9 gem installed for my app, so I add this line to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '= 1.3.9'
```

However, when I run 'bundle install', it installs v1.4.2 of that gem.

I modified the above line to

```
gem 'sqlite3', '= 1.3.9', '< 1.4'
```

No joy -- sqlite v1.4.2 is installed (even if I remove any reference to 'sqlite3' from the Gemfile completely).

My Gemfile was created when I used `rails new appname`, so it is not fancy at all... I only added `gem devise` to it.

Gemfile.lock doesn't contain any reference to  sqlite3. I removed it anyway and it didn't help.

As another option, I installed v1.3.9 via `gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.9` and I removed v1.4.2 with

```
# bundle exec gem uninstal sqlite3

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. sqlite3-1.3.9
 2. sqlite3-1.4.2
 3. All versions
> 2
Successfully uninstalled sqlite3-1.4.2
```

...but as soon as I tried to add v1.3.9, I got:

```
# bundle add sqlite3 -v 1.3.9

[!] There was an error parsing `injected gems`: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: sqlite3 (~> 1.4) and sqlite3 (= 1.3.9). Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from injected gems:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  gem "sqlite3", "= 1.3.9"
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I'd grateful for any hints on why v1.4.2 keeps being installed and, most importantly, how do get the bundler forget about v1.4.2 and accept v1.3.9?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *`gem 'sqlite3', '= 1.3.9'` ... it installs v1.4.2 of that gem.*" -- Seriously?? Sorry to sound like a non-believer, but... *I don't believe you :D*. I think there is something very silly going on in the `Gemfile`. Are you able to share the full `Gemfile`?

Comment: In particular, that final error message: *You specified: sqlite3 (~> 1.4)* -- Huh??? Why does it think you specified `~> 1.4`?

Comment: Is there something else in the Gemfile that depends on sqlite3 ? If you search the Gemfil.lock for sqlite3 it will show you if another gem has that requirement

Answer (score 2):

There might be some gem in your app that requires `sqlite3-1.4.2` and that is causing an issue with installing `sqlite3-1.3.9`. You should check your Gemfile.lock and look for any gem that is adding `sqlite3-1.4.2` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a gem in your app that requires sqlite3-1.4.2 and that is causing an issue with installing sqlite3-1.3.9. You should check your Gemfile.lock and look for any gem that is adding sqlite3-1.4.2 as a dependency.